# Javascript Evaluation Questions (Part 2)

Tags: javascript

```
(function () {
    var x = 5; 

    (function () {
        function f(y) { return (x+y)-2 };

        (function () {
            function g(h) { var x = 7; return h(x) };

           (function () { var x=10; z=g(f); })();
        })();
    })();
})();
```

I'm working through some problems from my textbook in my class to prepare for our next exam, and can't figure out how the above evaluates.

Mostly, I don't understand the call z=g(f), as when f is evaluated, it isn't provided an argument, so how does it evaluate at all? How does it know what y is? What would g(f) evaluate to?

Also, as far as scoping goes, I believe javascript treats most everything as global variables, so the last x that is set would be the x value used in function f, correct?

Thanks for any help!

**Please note, these are extra problems in the back of the book I'm practicing to prepare for the exam, these are not direct homework questions.**

Comment: Isn't this the same question you just asked? Minus the wrapping function.

Comment: @meder, it's similar but not the same.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - I know the code isn't exactly the same, but the tips given to him in the last answer should give him enough to solve this one.

Comment: It is similar, but I just needed some explanation as to the anonymous functions. Should the tips from the last be enough for this one? I was guessing the scoping would change for this, resulting in a different evaluation for g(f)...

Comment: @OogaBooga - Read http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Comment: @Meder: Thanks! Heading to take a look now. :)

Comment: Do these two different questions evaluate to the same answer? I believe they do, as the only difference is that each line from the first question is now enclosed in an anonymous function.

Comment: @OogaBooga, that's the key difference, as I explain in my answer below.  Braces alone don't create a new scope; anonymous functions do.  So the result is different.

Answer (score 1):

In this case of `g(f)` the function `f` is not evaluated but instead is passed as an object / value.  Functions are values in javascript and can be passed as such.  The function `g` later evaluates the function `f` via the expression `h(x)` (because `f` is passed as the parameter `h`)

Here's a more direct example

```
var addOne = function(x) { return x+1; }
var f = addOne;
var value = f(4); // Returns 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps to have better formatting and indentation so that it's easier to investigate what's happening:

```
(function() {
    var x = 5;
    (function() {
        function f(y) { // <-- y is the x from function g
            return (x + y) - 2
        };
        (function() {
            function g(h) {
                var x = 7;  // <-- local x is defined and passed to f
                return h(x) // <-- h === f
            };
            (function() {
                var x = 10;
                z = g(f);  // <-- f is passed to g
            })()
        })()
    })()
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to format it, but it was confusing the hell out of me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined within functions are scoped to that function. You should probably figure out the rest from there if this is really for a class.

Answer (score 0):

> Mostly, I don't understand the call
>   z=g(f), as when f is evaluated, it
>   isn't provided an argument, so how
>   does it evaluate at all? How does it
>   know what y is? What would g(f)
>   evaluate to?

If you look at how `g` is implemented:

```
function g(h) { var x = 7; return h(x) };
```

It takes an argument `h`, which is a `Function`, and then calls it as `h(x)`. I hope this helps you understand how `z = g(f)` ends up running function `f`.

> Also, as far as scoping goes, I
>   believe javascript treats most
>   everything as global variables, so the
>   last x that is set would be the x
>   value used in function f, correct?

Incorrect. When the `var` statement is used, a new variable in the local scope is defined. In your case, the final `x` is not global.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, my question I suppose is what does g(f) evaluate to? I would guess, like the last question I asked, it evaluates to 10+7-2.

Answer (score 0):

I also [beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) it for readability.

```
(function () {
    var x = 5;
```

This sets a local variable `x` to 5.

```
    (function () {
        function f(y) {
            return (x + y) - 2
        };
```

This creates a local function `f`; note that the above `x` (currently 5) is closed in.

```
        (function () {
            function g(h) {
                var x = 7;
                return h(x)
            };
```

We define a function `g` that takes a function `h` as a parameter.  It has a local variable `x`, which shadows the other one.

```
            (function () {
                var x = 10;
                z = g(f);
            })()
```

This `x` is a red herring; it shadows the outer one, and is never actually used.  We then call `g`, passing `f`.  Going above to `g`, we see that `f` becomes formal parameter `h`, and is called with 7.  In `f`, that becomes `y`.  So we get `(5 + 7) - 2`, 10.  Due to the shadowing, it is *not* equivalent to the other code.

The outer `x` is never modified, just shadowed.